# how to expose boost::ptr_multimap to python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, pointer-container

I am trying to expose a global boost::ptr_multimap that lives in the c++ world to python.

As the released boost::python suite doesn't include support for multimap, I have cloned code from here:

https://github.com/JohnReid/boost-indexing-suite/blob/master/indexing_suite/multimap.hpp

which seems to support std::multimap.

I wonder if anyone has had a successful experience doing this?

Otherwise, if ptr_multimap simply doesn't make sense in python, and the need is only for a copy of the c++ object, what is the most convenient way to expose that multimap?